# How do I create run configurations for running junit tests via maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an app in which the junit tests should be run via a maven command like this :

```
mvn test -Dtest=MyCodeTestClassJavaName -Dbase_url=https://myapp-test-environment.com
```

I can run this via commandline, but I cannot do it in eclipse. Could someone please show me how to do it in eclipse ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `"test"` and `"base_url"` as environment variables in Eclipse. [Here's docs](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_env.htm) how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Should I create a maven run configuration for this first & then set the environment for that config as you have shown above ?

Comment: You can create maven run config and pass the env vars in the Environment window.

Comment: In maven config, I entered the root of the project. Then, I set the goal as test. It ran multiple tests instead of the single test I wanted.

Comment: did you pass the env variable test=MyCodeTestClassJavaName to maven in your run configuration in Eclipse?

Comment: I tried something myself and it worked. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it myself and made it work. Here is the answer :

1 - Create a maven build configuration. Refer the image.
[image]

2 - Base directory = your project root.

3 - Goal = test

4 - Add the parameters in your maven command, that is :

```
test = MyCodeTestClassJavaName
base_url = https://myapp-test-environment.com
```